# How to store a PHP variable until another request

Tags: php, variables, get

How can I store a PHP variable in a PHP script, and then use that same variable in an another PHP script?

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
<?php                       
                    session_start();
                            $util=$_POST['util'];
                            $pw=$_POST['pw'];
                            include("abrebdvendas.php");
                            //testar a exist�ncia de liga��o ao MySQL
                            $ligax=mysql_connect($host,$user,$senha);
                            if (!$ligax) {
                                    echo 'Erro: Falha na liga&#231;&#227;o'.'<br>';
                                    exit;
                                    }
                                    //ligar � base de dados vendas
                                    mysql_select_db($dbname,$ligax);
                                    //criar uma query para inser��o do registo
                                    $lista="select * from utilizador where util='$util' and pw='$pw'";
                                    $result=mysql_query($lista) or die(mysql_error());
                                    $dados = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                                    $u=$dados['util'];
                                    $p=$dados['pw'];
                            if ($u=='' or $p=='')
                            {
                            echo "Tente de novo";
                            echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=http://localhost/ola1/Site/Sem%20Log%20In/longin.html">';
                            } 
                            else if ($u==$util and $p==$pw)
                                    {
                                    //obter tipo valor
                                    echo '<h2>Bem vindo '.$util.'</h2><br>';
                                    $paulo=$_POST['util'];
                                    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="100; URL=http://localhost/ola1/Site/Com%20LogIn/paginicial.php">';

                                     $_SESSION['myNumber']=$num;                
                                                                        }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    echo "Tente de novo";
                                    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0.1; URL=http://localhost/ola1/Site/Sem%20Log%20In/longin.html">';
                                    }                                   
                    ?>
```

The code is from [here](http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/form.html).

Comment: I don't know, its a good question

Comment: the answer is a combo of all 3 - Dhruvisha spells it all out on how to use the sessions.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the deprecation process. Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you want to use value of some variable which is stored in another variable in another page ,you should use $_SESSION[] as below:

```
 $_SESSION['myNumber']=$num;
```

You need to start session at the top of the php page as below:

```
 <?php
ob_start();
@session_start();
?>
```

And get variable from another php file as below

```
$newnum = $_SESSION['myNumber'];
```

Comment: i get this error `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at G:\xampplite\htdocs\ola1\Site\Sem Log In\info_login.php:52) in G:\xampplite\htdocs\ola1\Site\Sem Log In\info_login.php on line 53      

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at G:\xampplite\htdocs\ola1\Site\Sem Log In\info_login.php:52) in G:\xampplite\htdocs\ola1\Site\Sem Log In\info_login.php on line 53`

Comment: have u started session in some other php file also?

Comment: it should be the first line in your file.

Comment: write ob_start(); before session_start();

Comment: i will have to go i will be back in a bit

Answer (score 1):

Using sessions, the first line must be `session_start();`

Then you can store some values with `$num = $_SESSION['myNumber'];` and utilize it in others operations.

Answer (score 0):

you can store them as session variables

```
$_SESSION['myNumber'] = $num;
```